# Is there a difference between 1.week and 1.weeks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a difference between `1.week` and `1.weeks` or are they synonymous?

Comment: Simply for readability `1.week` reads more naturally than `1.weeks`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-week):

> `week()`
>
> Alias for: `weeks`
>
> ---
>
> `weeks()`
>
> Returns a Duration instance matching the number of weeks provided.
>
> ```
> 2.weeks # => 2 weeks
> ```
>
> aliased as: `week`

Answer (score 2):

`week` is just [an alias](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-week) for `weeks`.

Answer (score 1):

They are synonymous:

```
> 1.week == 1.weeks   
=> true                                     
> 42.week == 42.weeks 
=> true
```